# Differential Equations: Finding the increasing/decreasing values of autonomous diff eq.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question gives the differential equation:

$${dP\over dt} = 0.4P\left(1-{P\over 230}\right)$$

The textbook question is, "**For what values of $P$ is the population (b) increasing and (c) decreasing.**"

I understand that we must first find the values of $P$ the population is in equilibrium which are $P = 0$ and $P = 230$, but I'm generally confused on how the bounds for the values of $P$ when they are increasing, as the solution states that "if the population is increasing if $\frac{dP}{dt} > 0$ and decreasing if $\frac{dP}{dt} < 0$.

Where do the values of equilibrium play into finding this increase/decrease thing and how do I solve that question?

Answer (score 3):

Since $\frac{dP}{dt}$ means the change in the population with respect to time, we know that the population is increasing when $\frac{dP}{dt}>0$ and decreasing when $\frac{dP}{dt}<0.$  Since we know $\frac{dP}{dt}=0$ when $P = 0$ and $P = 230$, you just need to look at the sign of $\frac{dP}{dt}$ on the intervals  $(0,230)$, and $(230,\infty)$.  We ignore the interval $(-\infty,0)$ because it is not physically relevant. If $P\in (0,230)$ we see that $0.4P>0$ and $\frac{P}{230}<1$ so $\frac{dP}{dt}>0$ and the population is increasing.  If $P>230$ then $0.4P>0$ and $\frac{P}{230} > 1$ so $\frac{dP}{dt}<0$ and the population is decreasing.